# Django Error: "Unknown column 'categorytree.id' in 'field list'"

Tags: django, django-models

When running the following command via the Django shell:

```
from myApp.models import *
print Categorytree.objects.all()
```

I receive this error message:

> OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'categorytree.id' in 'field
>   list'")

This is what my Model looks like:

```
class Categorytree(models.Model):
    level = models.IntegerField(db_column='Level')  # Field name made lowercase.
    categorynode_idcategorynode = models.ForeignKey(Categorynode, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='CategoryNode_idCategoryNode')  # Field name made lowercase.
    categorynode_idancestorcategorynode = models.ForeignKey(Categorynode, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='CategoryNode_idAncestorCategoryNode', related_name='+')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'categorytree'
        unique_together = (('categorynode_idcategorynode', 'categorynode_idancestorcategorynode'),)
```

Note that it does not have a Primary Key and it shouldn't have, but Django seems to think there would be an Primary Key .id Field.

Comment: You have to have a primary key.

Comment: In the corresponding MySQL database design that table shouldn't have a primary key.
Is it correct to add one in the models.py then?

Answer (score 5):

To quote [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields):

> Each model requires exactly one field to have **primary_key=True** (either explicitly declared or automatically added).

If you need to access the table without primary key, you need to employ some other tool, like [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/ormconfiguration.html#how-do-i-map-a-table-that-has-no-primary-key).

Comment: Why does Django not automatically add one in my case?

Comment: Ah, my corresponding MySQL Database Table does also have to have a Primary Key column added?

Comment: Django does actually try to add one, as, again, stated by the docs: "By default, Django gives each model the following field: `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`". But `id` is not in the table schema, so it throws the error you see.

Comment: I am not actually sure that you definitely *need* to have a primary key in the table if you have `managed = False`. But Django expects the given "primary key" to behave like one: to uniquely identify a single record (so, no duplicates).