# Django Rest Framework- foreign key throwing error

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I am using django rest framework wherein the model has composite primary key, one of the them being a foreign key.

models/TestSuite.py

```
class TestSuite(models.Model):
     team_name = models.ForeignKey('Team', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='team_name')
     suite_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
     schedule = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
     email_list_ok = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
     email_list_fail = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
     template_name = models.ForeignKey('EmailTemplates', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='template_name')

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'test_suite'
    unique_together = (('team_name', 'suite_name'),)
```

models/Team.py

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'team'
```

TestSuiteSerializer.py

```
class Meta:
    model = models.TestSuite
    fields = '__all__'
```

TestSuiteViewSet.py

```
class TestSuiteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.TestSuite.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.TestSuiteSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data,
                                     many=isinstance(request.data, list))
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data,
                    status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Now when I do a post request, it throws below errors

When the post() has team_name already existing in team table

```html
{
    "team_name": [
        "test suite with this team name already exists."
    ]
}
```

When the post() has team_name not existing in team table

```html
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: 
Cannot assign "'dummy'": "TestSuite.team_name" must be a "Team" instance.
```

Can someone please help me here. I am assuming I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to your foreign key fields should be the model itself, not a string of the model (eg. not 'Team', but Team - likewise for EmailTemplate)

```
 class TestSuite(models.Model):
     # Change this field's first argument from a string to the Team class
     team_name = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='team_name')
     suite_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
     schedule = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
     email_list_ok = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
     email_list_fail = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
     # Change this field's first argument from a string to the EmailTemplates class
     template_name = models.ForeignKey(EmailTemplates, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='template_name')

     class Meta:
         managed = False
         db_table = 'test_suite'
         unique_together = (('team_name', 'suite_name'),)
```

Comment: The PK for TestSuite is ('team_name', 'suite_name'). Without assigning the primary key to one of the folders, the request fails. (1054, "Unknown column 'test_suite.id' in 'field list'")
If I set primarykey = True for team_name and/or suite_name, it fails as mentioned in the question.

Comment: What do you mean by folders? TestSuite does not have any primary keys in your model above, only your constraint of unique together ('team_name', 'suite_name'). I'm not suggesting any changes to your primary keys, you just didn't configure your foreign key fields properly. Make the change I suggested above and this will work.

Comment: Updated my answer to help you understand

Comment: folder was a error, I meant teams. I made the above changes as you suggest, the get() post() works.
However, the browsable api now shows an error when I click on it.
Exception Value: 
(1054, "Unknown column 'test_suite.id' in 'field list'")

Comment: class TestSuiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = TestSuite
        fields = ('id', 'team_name', 'suite_name', 'description', 'schedule', 'email_list_ok', 'email_list_fail', 'template_name')

Comment: Change your TestSuiteSerializer to the above, you'll probably need to make serializers for your Team and EmailTemplates too

Comment: I changed the TestSuiteSerializer. I already have the Team and EmailTemplates serializers
from rest_framework import serializers
from dqf_api import models


class EmailTemplatesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.EmailTemplates
        fields = '__all__'

Still getting the same error: (1054, "Unknown column 'test_suite.id' in 'field list'")

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40862994/django-error-unknown-column-categorytree-id-in-field-list

Comment: Please accept my answer as this is a different problem entirely and I resolved your problem